# How can Integrate LUIS when I have Waterfall step context object in Python?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have tried a lot, but seems like luis only takes turncontext object. Please help.

Comment: Hi B78. Can you post your code? I think I understand what you mean, but I need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

In a method

```
async def ask_name_step(self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext) -> DialogTurnResult:
```

you can't pass the step_context to Luis Recognizer, but you can pass **step_context.context**. This will work.

```
luis_result = await LuisRecognizer.recognize(step_context.context)
```